# Is it possible to touch the ImageView inside CollapsingToolbarLayout and scroll it?

Tags: android, imageview, android-collapsingtoolbarlayout, android-appbarlayout

I'm trying to get a fullscreen `CollapsingToolbar` but when I set `match_parent` to the height of `AppBarLayout` I'm not able to scroll the `ImageView` which is inside `CollapsingToolbarLayout`. I have to leave some space so that I can touch the "white" of the activity (in AppBarLayout I added *android:layout-marginBottom:"16dp"* ) and only then, after I touched it, I can scroll the ImageView otherwise I can't.
This happens everytime I run the app and touch the layout for the first time. So I have to touch the white first and then scroll the image.

Could you help me?

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:id="@+id/drawer">

<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/app_bar_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

        <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:id="@+id/collapsing_toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed"
            app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:expandedTitleMarginStart="48dp"
            app:expandedTitleMarginEnd="64dp">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/image"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
                app:layout_collapseMode="parallax"
                android:contentDescription="@null"
                android:src="@drawable/background" />

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
                app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
                app:theme="@style/ToolbarTheme"
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"/>

        </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:id="@+id/scroll"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:clipToPadding="false"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

        <FrameLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        </FrameLayout>

    </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>

<com.myapplication.ScrimInsetsFrameLayout
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="304dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    app:insetForeground="#4000"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:background="#ffffff">

    ...

</com.myapplication.ScrimInsetsFrameLayout>

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

**EDIT** @PPartisan I've done what you said but here's what I got:

[image]

Comment: it doesn't scroll because there's no code inside `CollapsingToolbarLayout` class to handle touches and make it scroll. You can test it using a `200dp` height and try scrolling touching directly on the `CollapsingToolbarLayout` or on the `ScrollView`. The on the scrollview works, on the toolbar it doesn't. The best advice is to change your layout, maybe something that looks like the header inside the ScrollView.

Comment: I think I won't get the same result. But I see apps like Google play that have a collapsing toolbar and there's no problem on touching it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This isn't a nice solution, but it does work on my test device. It kick starts the scrolling process by explicitly assigning a touch listener to the AppBar that triggers a nested scroll.

First, create a custom class that extends `NestedScrollView` and add the following method so it look something like this:

```
public class CustomNestedScrollView extends NestedScrollView {

    private int y;

    public CustomNestedScrollView(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public CustomNestedScrollView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    public boolean dispatchHandlerScroll(MotionEvent e) {
        switch (e.getAction()) {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                y = (int) e.getY();
                startNestedScroll(2);
                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                int dY = y - ((int)e.getY());
                dispatchNestedPreScroll(0, dY, null, null);
                dispatchNestedScroll(0, 0, 0, dY, null);
                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                stopNestedScroll();
                break;
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

Then, inside your `Activity` class, assign a `TouchListener` to your `AppBarLayout`:

```
appBarLayout.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        return customNestedScrollView.dispatchHandlerScroll(event);
    }
});
```

and remove it when the AppBar collapses fully for the first time:

```
@Override
public boolean dispatchTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
    if (Math.abs(appBarLayout.getY()) == appBarLayout.getTotalScrollRange()) {
        appBarLayout.setOnTouchListener(null);
    }
    return super.dispatchTouchEvent(ev);
}
```

**Edit**

Take the following steps to get it up and running:

- Replace the `NestedScrollView` in your `xml`(`android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView`) with the `CustomNestedScrollView` (which will take the form of `com.something.somethingelse.CustomNestedScrollView`, depending on where it is in your project).
- Assign it to a variable in your `Activity` `onCreate()`(i.e. `CustomScrollView customScrollView = (CustomScrollView) findViewById(R.id.custom_scroll_view_id);`)
- Set up the `TouchListener` on your `appBarLayout` as you have done in your edit. Now when you call `dispatchHandlerScroll()`, it will be on your `customNestedScrollView` instance.
- `dispatchTouchEvent()` is a method you override in your `Activity` class, so it should be outside the `TouchListener`

So, for example:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private AppBarLayout appBarLayout;
    private CustomNestedScrollView customNestedScrollView;
    //...
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        //...
        customNestedScrollView = (CustomNestedScrollView) findViewById(R.id.scroll);

        appBarLayout = (AppBarLayout) findViewById(R.id.app_bar_layout);
        appBarLayout.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
             public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                 return customNestedScrollView.dispatchHandlerScroll(event);
             }
        });
    }    

    @Override
    public boolean dispatchTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
        if (Math.abs(appBarLayout.getY()) == appBarLayout.getTotalScrollRange()) {
            appBarLayout.setOnTouchListener(null);
        }
        return super.dispatchTouchEvent(ev);
    }
}
```

Hope that's cleared things up.

Comment: What is _customAppBarLayout_ in _dispatchTouchEvent_ method?

Comment: @Rick Just a typo - it should be `appBarLayout` as well.

Comment: @Rick Added an edit that goes into more detail on how this works, let me know if you need anything else made clearer.

Comment: When I override _dispatchTouchEvent_ I get "Cannot resolve symbol 'appBarLayout' "

Comment: @Rick That is usually just caused by something simple, like not closing a bracket somewhere, or through mistyping a variable name.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/92612/discussion-between-ppartisan-and-rick).

Comment: Finally the result I wanted! Thanks a lot :)

Comment: @PPartisan Thanks for such a great solution I spent almost 1 days for find-out solution of that...

Answer (score 0):

Try to add a tiny margin so the white space below will be almost invisible (you might also want to change white to accent color so the space will not be visible)

Another approach is to set the height of app bar layout dynamically by getting the height of the screen.

EDIT:
This might be a focus problem, try to add dummy layout to your main content, that will be focused automatically

```
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0px"
        android:layout_height="0px"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="true" />
```

or even just add these attributes to your content layout

```
android:focusable="true"
android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
```

Comment: I've already tried setting marginBottom to 1dp but the problem is that I have to touch the white space to scroll the ImageView (this happens only when I first run the app).

Comment: So when you run your app 2nd time you don't need to touch "white" to scroll ?

Comment: Nope, forgive my english, everytime I run the app. There's no problem the second time I scroll the ImageView

Comment: I tried adding _android:focusable="true"
android:focusableInTouchMode="true"_ to **AppBarLayout** but I still cannot scroll it

Comment: Do you have any other idea?

Comment: Not yet, trying to figure it out